# Deployment of Hexo Application into Modulus.io

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create a blog post using [Hexo](http://zespia.tw/hexo/). It's working fine on local deployment. I'm using [Modulus](https://modulus.io/) as my [nodejs](http://nodejs.org/) hosting. The problem here is that hexo application starts with `hexo server` command unlike `node app.js` command. Also the main file of application `_config.yml` unlike `app.js or server.js` of nodejs. [Modulus](https://modulus.io/) deployment starts application with `node main-file.js` command rather than `hexo server` command. So, my application unable to start when deployed to Modulus server. Please suggest something on how to host [Hexo](http://zespia.tw/hexo/) in [Modulus](https://modulus.io/).

Answer (score 0):

## 1. Hexo can generate static pages

you can just run:

```
$ hexo generate
```

And the generated static pages will locate in `public/`.

Check the doc for more details: http://hexo.io/docs/generating.html

## 2. You can run hexo from .js

If you really want to run hexo server, and have to load it from .js file, it's ok. Just add a single line code file `app.js` with following content:

```
require('hexo').init({command: 'server'});
```

So, you can just run it with whatever method you want.

For more details, please check: http://hexo.io/docs/server.html#Forever_/_PM2

Comment: dancefire@ how do we pass IP and PORT from command? in app.js